# Force dissimilar images to equal heights so combined widths fill fixed div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been searching for the past few hours for a way to simplify what I'm currently doing manually. I have divs that are scaling all my images to a width of 500px. This is generally fine but some of my images are too small to be scaled that wide.

So I'm trying to put these smaller images side-by-side in a new 500px wide div. These smaller images will often have different height/width ratios from each other so I'm forcing them to be equal in height (+/- 1 pixel) so that their combined widths will be 500px. This keeps the outer edges lined up exactly with the edges of the single images above or below them. In this example I'm setting each image height manually like this:

```
    <!-- SIDE BY SIDE DIV -->    
<div style="width:500px;"> 
    <!-- IMAGE 01 -->
<div class="postContainer" id="imgContainer">
    <a href="http://example.com/example.jpg" imageanchor="1">
    <img height="248px" src="http://example.com/example.jpg" /></a>
        <div class="postTextbox">
            <div class="postText">Snappy comment.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- IMAGE 02 -->
<div class="postContainer" id="imgContainer">
    <a href="http://example.com/example.jpg" imageanchor="1">
    <img height="248px" src="http://example.com/example.jpg" /></a>
        <!-- <div class="postTextbox"><div class="postText">NO COMMENT.</div></div> --></div>
</div>
    <!-- END SIDE BY SIDE DIV -->
```

[JSFiddle Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/5ny6bep9/19/)

I'm trying to figure out if there's a more automated approach (through script maybe?) to finding the "magic" height number that will result in both images' widths equaling 500px since finding it manually by guess-and-check or simple math is getting kind of cumbersome.

I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I just couldn't dig up an answer.

Thank you very much for any guidance!

**UPDATE:**

I've been working on this a little based on Lathejockey81's example and think I've got it working so that the script only targets a specific div class so you can decide which images to show alone and which images to group together. You can also group more than two images side by side. However, it only seems to function properly in Chrome at the moment...

```
var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName('x2');
var divWidth = 500
var imgPad = 4
var pairs = []

function addUp(val, maxh, maxW) {
    var theWidths = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
        theWidths += Math.round(val[j].naturalWidth * (maxh / val[j].naturalHeight));
    }
    return theWidths;
}
// Find img tags in x2 divs & covert to array
for (var i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
var pair = x2[i].getElementsByTagName('img');
var arr = [].slice.call(pair);
pairs.push(arr);
}

for (x = 0; x < pairs.length; x++) {
var pairsX = pairs[x],
    pairsXlen = pairsX.length;
// Adds padding depending on # of images
var maxWidth = divWidth - (imgPad * (pairsXlen - 1));
var addWidths = 0;
var startHeight = 20;
for (var i = 0; addWidths < maxWidth; i++) {
    // Step heights up by 1
    newHeight = startHeight + i;
    for (y = 0; y < pairsXlen; y++) {
        pairsX[y].style.height = newHeight + 'px';
        // Add up the widths
        addWidths = addUp(pairsX, newHeight, maxWidth);
        // Jump out when width's exceeded
        if (addWidths > maxWidth) {
            break}
        }
    }
}
```

Since I've never written javascript before I appreciate any feedback on what can be done to improve this script, in particular why it's not quite working in FF or IE.

Thanks again for looking!

**UPDATE # 2:**

It seems to have been a styling issue.

```
.widthVal {
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

With this in place the images are not getting bumped down to the next line in FireFox or IE. Though the outermost image edges are not *quite* pixel perfectly aligned in IE, they're close enough for me.

I have since learned that the 'center' tag has been deprecated so I'll be removing that, too!

Here is the new working example: [**Example working in Big 3 browsers.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ny6bep9/19/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to demonstrate the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ny6bep9/7/).

You need to sort through all the images, and pair up the skinny ones, then you can calculate their new heights.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

var tooSmall = []; // Collection of smallPairs
var smallPair = []; // a pair of images to shrink

// Calculates width after first shrink
var newWidth = function (image, newHeight) {
    return image.naturalWidth * (newHeight/image.naturalHeight);
};

// If a single image is too narrow, grab the next regardless of its width
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
    if (smallPair.length !== 1 && (images[i].naturalWidth > 500 || smallPair.length > 1)) {        
        // Shrink any image too wide
        if(images[i].naturalWidth > 500) {
            images[i].setAttribute('width','500px');
        }        
        if(smallPair.length > 1) {
            tooSmall.push(smallPair);
        }
        smallPair = [];
    }
    else {
        smallPair.push(images[i]);
    } 
}

// Loop through image pairs and shrink them
for(var i=0;i<tooSmall.length;i++) {
    var newHeight = tooSmall[i][0].naturalHeight;
    if(tooSmall[i][1].naturalHeight < newHeight) {
        newHeight = tooSmall[i][1].naturalHeight;
    }
    var totalWidth = newWidth(tooSmall[i][0], newHeight) + newWidth(tooSmall[i][1], newHeight);
    var sizeRatio = 496 / totalWidth; // Use 496 width to account for padding
    newHeight = Math.round(newHeight * sizeRatio);
    tooSmall[i][0].setAttribute('height', newHeight + 'px'); 
    tooSmall[i][1].setAttribute('height', newHeight + 'px');
}
```

If you're looking to make a static page there may be easier solutions, but this should work either way. If you're dynamically loading content there are server-side options as well.

Comment: This is really nice. This would do a perfect job of automatically arranging every image on the page. I'm just barely getting my feet wet in javascript but I'm going to see if I can modify this to shrink only specific tagged images, even if they're big. That way I can still choose which images display side by side. I'm going to spend sometime studying this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing you might notice is I removed the Id properties you put on your images. Id properties should be unique in the context of the entire page. If you want to limit your search to selected photos, give them an identifying class and use `getElementsByClassName'. You'll also notice multiple classes can be assigned by separating them with spaces.

Comment: I did notice that. Very helpful. It looks like I've been misusing Ids, whoops! I'll go back and replace them with classes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi again, I updated my question with code I wrote based on your example. It works exactly as I was hoping (as far as I can tell) in Chrome, but the results are not the same in IE or FireFox. I was wondering when you had a minute if maybe you could take a look. The resizing appears to be more-or-less correct but the images are not staying confined to their divs, instead getting bumped down to the next row. How can I coerce the other browsers to handle it like Chrome does? Thanks!

Comment: I looked at it in IE and got the same result as Chrome. This might be a situation where bumping up the div width a little to allow the browser to think it has room might be a solution - it's a little hackey, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this requires calculation with values of multiple elements, this can't be done with pure CSS. So indeed, some script will need to do the work.

The math should be quite obvious. If you have two images (width * height), one with a size `A * B` and another one with the size `X * Y` you can come up with the following equations (with `.n` marking the new values, `r` and `s` being the scale ratios):

```
Bn = Yn
An + Xn = 500

An = r * A, Bn = r * B
Xn = s * X, Yn = s * Y

s = 500 / ( (Y * A / B) + X)
```

As an example, two images sized 120*50px and 200*300px you would end up with a common height of 163px and widths of 392 and 108px, respectively (392 + 108 = 500).

So, what you need is to write a script that retrieves the image path from divs containing more than one image, get the original image dimensions (possibly by using the Filereader object), insert the values into the equation and apply the new size to the image tags.

Comment: I know this is probably simple math but it still makes my head spin. Can you explain what's happening when you're solving for `s`?  Also, what would that same `s` equation look like if you had three images instead of two? Is there one equation that could handle any number of variables or is the equation specific to the number of variable you have? Thanks for your patience with me :)

Comment: I wound up using a loop to solve for situations where I'd want to resize more than two images in a row using an equation I found very similar to your example. Thanks again.