# How to get parentNode ID and use it as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run a script on images within specific blog posts. Each post div is given a unique ID by Blogger that I'm trying to get. Because I only want to run the script on posts containing the function call and not the entire page, I want the function to basically find the ID of the div that's calling it, store that ID as a variable, and then pass that variable in to my function.

```
<script>
var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
</script>
```

This returns the correct element but the second I wrap it in a `function(){}` it doesn't work anymore. How can I assign these variables from within a function so I don'thave to clutter up every post's html with a bunch of variable declarations?

Secondly, once I have these variables assigned is there a way to use the value stored with the getElementByID method to actually select the element?

```
var parentDivID = parentTag.id;
var postID = document.getElementByID(parentDivID); //can't figure out how to select using this as the variable
```

For ease of use I'd like it if I could simply wrap the function call in script tags and stick it at the end of my post's html whenever I need to use it.

**Details**

The script I want to run finds images within divs with a specified class and resizes them to fit side-by-side so that the outer edges of the images completely fill the width of the div.

Here is the question covering that script:

[Force dissimilar images to equal heights so combined widths fill fixed div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755169/force-dissimilar-images-to-equal-heights-so-combined-widths-fill-fixed-div)

I would like to call this script at the end of any post body where I plan to use side-by-side formatting. The reason I want to call it at the end of a post instead of on the entire page is because the page uses "infinite scrolling" and I'm worried that as posts load after the fact the resizing script will have already been run and newly loaded posts will not be resized.

So I want the function to be able to find the unique ID of the div that contains the call, use that as a variable and ask the script to look inside that post for divs of a certain class, then look within those divs for image tags and resize those images. I hope that makes sense.

Here's an example of what I'd like the post's html to look like:

```
<div style="width:500px; margin:auto;">
<div class="widthVal x2">
<a href="sample01.jpg"><img class="caption" alt="Caption 01" src="sample01.jpg" /></a>
<a href="sample02.jpg"><img class="caption" alt="Caption 02" src="sample02.jpg" /></a>
<a href="sample03.jpg"><img class="caption"alt="Caption 03" src="sample03.jpg" /></a>     
</div> 

<script> resizeMagic(); </script> 

</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you want to store all the postIds with the function to execute something later?

Comment: Not quite. And I could be going about this all wrong, but I just want the script to run when the post loads, but only if that post contains the function call wrapped in script tags.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand your problem. Could you explain what you want to do with this function?

Comment: Hi Pedro. I updated my question with additional details. Hopefully it makes more sense now. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Maybe you could store your data in an hidden field to use it elsewhere? (Not sur if I fully understand your problem)

Comment: @Yushbox Shoot. I'm sorry. I'll try to figure out how to make the question more clear.